# Too few parameters. Expected 1 error - When using DateDiff function of MS Access

Tags: java, ms-access, servlets, datediff

```
SELECT DateDiff("n", LastDate, Now()) as datediffs FROM UserLog WHERE ID = 1
```

When I execute this query from Query Design View (MS Access). This give me different in minutes well like this:

```
datediffs
---------
2826
```

But when I execute the same query (including static value in where condition ID = 1) from servlet like this:

```
strSql = "SELECT DateDiff(\"n\", LastDate, Now()) as datediffs FROM UserLog WHERE ID = 1";
recset=stmt.executeQuery(strSql);
```

It gives me the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected
>   1.

So what wrong with me?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216425 - referring to a column that does not exist...

Comment: @eis Yes. I checked it. But here I am using only one column `LastDate` which is available in `UserLog` table.

Comment: You are using two columns, LastDate and ID (`ID = 1`)

Comment: @Remou But both `LastDate` and `ID` are in my table.

Comment: So does `select top 5 id, lastdate from UserLog` work?

Comment: @Remou Yes it is executed from servlet.

Comment: I wonder is Now() the problem? Can you try something instead of now()? A real date or Date(). Occasionally, Now can cause a problem if the database has lost references.

Comment: @Remou I executed `SELECT DateDiff(\"n\", LastDate, '20-08-2012 5:15:10 PM')` Which did not executed. When I tried this one `SELECT LastDate, NOW() FROM ...` it was executed successfully. So I suspect the problem is with `Datediff()` function.

Comment: That is odd, because datediff works outside of MS Access. Aha http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=385ad421bcdae65da641072ba3da6?bug_id=4253498

Comment: @Remou Ohh.. So I can not use `Datediff()` function of Access from Java. I have to get datediff in minutes from Java.

Comment: Possibly. I notice one guy/ette said it was okay. If you are using a Jet connection, you might like to try ACE.

Comment: @Remou can you please turn these comments into an answer with some links for [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035536/too-few-parameters-expected-1-error-but-i-am-not-using-any-parameter#comment16068029_12035536) so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write-up of comments from above.

If

```
SELECT TOP 5 id, lastdate FROM UserLog
```

runs, then you need to look at the various other parts of your statement. For example, Now() can cause a problem if the database has lost references.

However, you report

> I executed SELECT DateDiff("n", LastDate, '20-08-2012 5:15:10 PM')
> Which did not executed. When I tried this one SELECT LastDate, NOW()
> FROM ... it was executed successfully. So I suspect the problem is
> with Datediff() function. (–- @hims056, OP)

Which is odd, because DateDiff notmally works outside of MS Access. However, I notice that this problem is reported in [Oracle Bugs](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=385ad421bcdae65da641072ba3da6?bug_id=4253498). In the comments, one person mentions that in his or her case, the problem was a misnamed column, so it may be possible to use ACE, rather than Jet for the connection. Alternatively, as you say, "get datediff in minutes from Java."

Comment: I have marked a community, because it was a joint endeavour. feel free to make corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a PreparedStatement instead:

```
strSql = "SELECT DateDiff(\"n\", LastDate, Now()) as datediffs FROM UserLog WHERE ID = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(strSql);
ps.setInt(1, 1);
recset = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: What is `ps.setInt(1, 1);`? This statement throws an exception. and giving null in `exception.getMessage();`

Comment: @hims056 If your ID is String, change ps.setString(1, "1").

Comment: My ID is Int. Now Error is like this: `[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2.`

Comment: @hims056 please test with select * firstly. I think your query may be wrong.

Comment: I Just executed `select top 5 id, lastdate from UserLog` which is executed successfully. (See comments in my question)